# Dijit Trouble set value of the combobox

Tags: javascript, combobox, dojo, dijit.form

I'm having trouble to set the value of the dojo `combobox` , the combo box is :

```
<select data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ComboBox" id="index" name="index" onChange="comboOnChange()">
     <option value="30" >30</option>
     <option value="50">50</option>
     <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

I've tried all these options:

```
dojo.widget.byId('index').setValue(index); 
index.options[index.selectedIndex].text = index;
dijit.byId('index').set("value", index);
```

None of them worked , any suggestion?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Set the value of your first option to XXX so that it now reads `<option value="XXX">30</option>`? Or do you want to select one of the options to be displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if you're using legacy dojo mode . but since 1.6 , dojo uses [AMD](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules/) style . in your case  `dijit.byId('index').set("value", index);` should work , let see your console if there are some errors !

But I recommend strongly to use modern Dojo (AMD) , Above you'll find a working example (it starts with 30 then change to 50 ):

```js
require(["dojo/ready", "dojo/parser","dijit/registry","dijit/form/ComboBox","dojo/domReady!"],
function (ready, parser, Registry ,Combobox) {
  parser.parse();
  //be sure the widget is rendered and parsed , by calling ready 
  ready(function(){
    //get reference to combo widget
    var combo = Registry.byId("index");
    // atach change event
    combo.on("change",function(e){
      console.log(e);
      alert(this.value);
    });
    //here you can set value to your combo set value 
    combo.set("value",50);
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Lucida Sans,Lucida Grande,Arial !important;
    font-size: 13px !important;
    background: white;
    color: #333;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script>
    dojoConfig= {
        parseOnLoad: false,
        async: true
    };
</script>
<body class="claro">
  <select data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ComboBox" id="index" name="index">
     <option value="30" >30</option>
     <option value="50">50</option>
     <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
</body>
```